# android studio 1.5.1, marshmallow how do i tell if the wifi router is turned off?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi, android-6.0-marshmallow

this is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282807/android-studio-1-5-1-marshmallow-no-internet-access-detected-wont-automaticall). the reason i want to know this is as follows:

this is a dedicated system. the tablets run in a kiosk mode. nobody else is on the router. the router is not connected to the internet. the wifi is close enough. so if it's on, it should connect. i think i foundf a way to force the connection (see related question).

trying the code below:

```
package acme.wifi;
import android.content.*;
import android.net.wifi.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.math.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.*;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    void retry() {
        WifiManager wifiMan=(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInf;
        int ipAddress;
        List<WifiConfiguration> wifiConfigurations=wifiMan.getConfiguredNetworks();
        System.out.println("wifi configurations (all): "+wifiConfigurations.size());
        for(WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration : wifiConfigurations) {
            if(wifiConfiguration.toString().contains("192.168.0.")) {
                System.out.println("found our network: "+wifiConfiguration.toString());
                System.out.println("SSID: "+wifiConfiguration.SSID);
                System.out.println("wifi configuration status is disabled: "+(wifiConfiguration.status==WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED));
                int networkId=wifiConfiguration.networkId;
                boolean ok=wifiMan.disconnect();
                System.out.println("disconnect() returns: "+ok);
                System.out.println("enabling our network: "+networkId);
                // https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2218
                ok=wifiMan.enableNetwork(networkId,true);
                System.out.println("enableNetwork() returns: "+ok);
                System.out.println("trying to recommect to wifi.");
                ok=wifiMan.reconnect();
                System.out.println("reconnect returns: "+ok);
                if(ok) {
                    wifiMan=(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    wifiInf=wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();
                    ipAddress=wifiInf.getIpAddress();
                    System.out.println("wifi ip adress: "+ipAddress);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    String getIpAddressFromWifiManager() {
        WifiManager wifiMan=(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        System.out.println("isWifiEnabled() returns: "+wifiMan.isWifiEnabled());
        WifiInfo wifiInf=wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();
        System.out.println("wifi info: "+wifiInf);
        int ipAddress=wifiInf.getIpAddress();
        System.out.println("wifi ip adress: "+ipAddress);
        if(ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN))
            ipAddress=Integer.reverseBytes(ipAddress);
        byte[] ipByteArray=BigInteger.valueOf(ipAddress).toByteArray();
        String ipAddressString=null;
        try {
            ipAddressString=InetAddress.getByAddress(ipByteArray).getHostAddress();
        } catch(UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to get host address.");
            if(true)
                retry();
        }
        return ipAddressString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view,"Replace with your own action",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action",null).show();
            }
        });
        String ipAddress=getIpAddressFromWifiManager();
        System.out.println("ip address: "+ipAddress);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id=item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if(id==R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

with the router off (power unplugged) i get:

```
02-22 18:12:38.073 3029-3035/? E/Sensors: sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
02-22 18:13:11.991 3049-3049/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
02-22 18:13:11.996 3049-3049/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
02-22 18:13:12.043 3049-3049/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
02-22 18:13:12.101 3049-3049/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
02-22 18:13:12.134 3049-3049/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
02-22 18:13:12.149 2478-2488/? D/DefContainer: Copying /data/local/tmp/acme.wifi to base.apk
02-22 18:13:12.408 589-613/? I/PackageManager.DexOptimizer: Running dexopt (dex2oat) on: /data/app/vmdl765778575.tmp/base.apk pkg=acme.wifi isa=arm vmSafeMode=false debuggable=true oatDir = /data/app/vmdl765778575.tmp/oat bootComplete=true
02-22 18:13:12.456 3062-3062/? I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --debuggable
02-22 18:13:12.768 3062-3065/? W/dex2oat: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
02-22 18:13:15.259 3062-3062/? I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 2.804s (threads: 4) arena alloc=410KB java alloc=2MB native alloc=11MB free=2MB
02-22 18:13:15.271 589-602/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping acme.wifi appid=10027 user=-1: uninstall pkg
02-22 18:13:15.271 589-602/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 2907:acme.wifi/u0a27 (adj 0): stop acme.wifi
02-22 18:13:15.283 589-1141/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 2
02-22 18:13:15.284 589-600/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{29f4f76 u0 acme.wifi/acme.wifi.MainActivity}
02-22 18:13:15.285 589-655/? D/WifiService: Client connection lost with reason: 4
02-22 18:13:15.363 589-613/? I/PackageManager: Package acme.wifi codePath changed from /data/app/acme.wifi-2 to /data/app/acme.wifi-1; Retaining data and using new
02-22 18:13:15.364 589-613/? W/PackageManager: Code path for acme.wifi changing from /data/app/acme.wifi-2 to /data/app/acme.wifi-1
02-22 18:13:15.364 589-602/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{a246708 u0 acme.wifi/.MainActivity t10}: app died, no saved state
02-22 18:13:15.366 589-613/? W/PackageManager: Resource path for acme.wifi changing from /data/app/acme.wifi-2 to /data/app/acme.wifi-1
02-22 18:13:15.549 589-613/? W/Settings: Setting install_non_market_apps has moved from android.provider.Settings.Global to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
02-22 18:13:15.550 589-613/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Explicit
02-22 18:13:15.554 589-602/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping acme.wifi appid=10027 user=-1: replace pkg
02-22 18:13:15.556 589-1375/? W/ActivityManager: Spurious death for ProcessRecord{a057741 0:acme.wifi/u0a27}, curProc for 2907: null
02-22 18:13:15.624 589-613/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 22496(1312KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(120KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 15MB/22MB, paused 1.892ms total 66.314ms
02-22 18:13:15.635 589-1145/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2907 uid 10027
02-22 18:13:15.644 589-613/? W/PackageManager: Couldn't remove dex file for package:  at location /data/app/acme.wifi-2/base.apk, retcode=-1
02-22 18:13:15.646 589-613/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping acme.wifi appid=10027 user=0: pkg removed
02-22 18:13:15.648 1240-1240/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()
02-22 18:13:15.648 3049-3049/? I/art: System.exit called, status: 0
02-22 18:13:15.648 3049-3049/? I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
02-22 18:13:15.687 589-589/? D/JobSchedulerService: Receieved: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
02-22 18:13:15.693 1328-1328/? D/CarrierServiceBindHelper: Receive action: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
02-22 18:13:15.693 589-633/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
02-22 18:13:15.695 1328-1328/? D/CarrierServiceBindHelper: mHandler: 3
02-22 18:13:15.753 1328-1328/? D/CarrierServiceBindHelper: Receive action: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
02-22 18:13:15.754 589-633/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
02-22 18:13:15.754 1328-1328/? D/CarrierServiceBindHelper: mHandler: 3
02-22 18:13:15.804 1328-1328/? D/CarrierServiceBindHelper: Receive action: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
02-22 18:13:15.809 1328-1328/? D/CarrierServiceBindHelper: mHandler: 3
02-22 18:13:15.809 1328-1328/? D/CarrierConfigLoader: mHandler: 9 phoneId: 0
02-22 18:13:15.812 589-633/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
02-22 18:13:15.827 1067-1067/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
02-22 18:13:15.827 1067-1067/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
02-22 18:13:15.834 1581-3093/? D/PackageBroadcastService: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=acme.wifi
02-22 18:13:15.840 1067-1067/? I/ConfigService: onCreate
02-22 18:13:15.841 1581-1581/? I/ConfigFetchService: onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:acme.wifi cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
02-22 18:13:15.971 1581-1581/? D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.play.games
02-22 18:13:15.971 1581-1581/? D/ChimeraModuleLdr: Module APK com.google.android.play.games already loaded
02-22 18:13:15.988 2613-2613/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1221 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:581 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:581 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2725 
02-22 18:13:16.052 1712-1712/? D/Finsky: [1] ExternalReferrer.access$200: Package state data is missing for acme.wifi
02-22 18:13:16.054 1581-1581/? D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.play.games
02-22 18:13:16.054 1581-1581/? D/ChimeraModuleLdr: Module APK com.google.android.play.games already loaded
02-22 18:13:16.066 1581-3107/? D/PackageBroadcastService: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=acme.wifi
02-22 18:13:16.067 1581-1581/? D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.play.games
02-22 18:13:16.067 1581-1581/? D/ChimeraModuleLdr: Module APK com.google.android.play.games already loaded
02-22 18:13:16.072 1581-1581/? D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.vision from APK com.google.android.gms
02-22 18:13:16.106 1396-3109/? I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi: Updating corpora: APPS=acme.wifi, CONTACTS=MAYBE
02-22 18:13:16.127 1581-1581/? I/ConfigFetchService: onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:acme.wifi cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
02-22 18:13:16.132 1581-1581/? I/ConfigFetchService: launchTask
02-22 18:13:16.136 1581-1581/? I/ConfigFetchService: service connected
02-22 18:13:16.143 1581-3112/? V/ConfigFetchTask: ConfigFetchTask getDeviceDataVersionInfo(): ABFEt1W7qltJwF1iJulsbhXPy8Qp2CrzzNOQI6MWXF9sHJDZmtbcmiI5EB0sDZYeZFlm9RKT7NEj4pWCv52R4KJK7ZsffG-MiSnM47B4Z4z8CEFlZCYuZVcJKYBtl0J4LJ9_hvX0J-eHUyqueU1-6jJZpzNWinD-UnN0XcBYgw3Lql2WnoLs1TBoqRHVrdAXk2aC14lVR9mxhfbrRJt0igPsOffgoJtD9lm3iX794XMqzibZOna4BMs
02-22 18:13:16.161 1581-3113/? I/PeopleContactsSync: CP2 sync disabled
02-22 18:13:16.163 1581-3112/? I/GoogleURLConnFactory: Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
02-22 18:13:16.176 1344-1467/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
02-22 18:13:16.176 1344-1467/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
02-22 18:13:16.186 1581-1581/? D/ConfigFetchService: ConfigApi connection successful.
02-22 18:13:16.207 1067-1067/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
02-22 18:13:16.208 1067-1067/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
02-22 18:13:16.221 1581-3112/? W/ConfigFetchTask: exception on config fetch: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "android.clients.google.com": No address associated with hostname
02-22 18:13:16.221 1581-1581/? I/ConfigFetchService: fetch service done; releasing wakelock
02-22 18:13:16.223 1581-1581/? I/ConfigFetchService: stopping self
02-22 18:13:16.233 1581-1581/? D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.vision from APK com.google.android.gms
02-22 18:13:16.233 1581-3117/? D/PackageBroadcastService: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED and uri=acme.wifi
02-22 18:13:16.248 1581-3118/? I/PeopleContactsSync: CP2 sync disabled
02-22 18:13:16.254 1396-3109/? I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi: UpdateCorporaTask done [took 148 ms] updated apps [took 148 ms] 
02-22 18:13:16.680 3097-3097/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
02-22 18:13:16.680 3100-3100/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
02-22 18:13:16.686 3097-3097/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
02-22 18:13:16.686 3100-3100/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
02-22 18:13:16.735 3100-3100/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
02-22 18:13:16.735 3097-3097/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
02-22 18:13:16.783 3097-3097/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
02-22 18:13:16.784 3100-3100/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
02-22 18:13:16.811 3100-3100/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
02-22 18:13:16.812 3097-3097/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm
02-22 18:13:16.815 3097-3097/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-22 18:13:16.817 589-1141/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=acme.wifi/.MainActivity} from uid 2000 on display 0
02-22 18:13:16.830 3100-3100/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-22 18:13:16.841 3147-3147/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-22 18:13:16.843 589-599/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 3147:acme.wifi/u0a27 for activity acme.wifi/.MainActivity
02-22 18:13:16.885 3147-3147/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/acme.wifi-1/lib/arm
02-22 18:13:16.980 589-655/? D/WifiService: New client listening to asynchronous messages
02-22 18:13:16.981 3147-3147/? I/System.out: isWifiEnabled() returns: true
02-22 18:13:16.982 3147-3147/? I/System.out: wifi info: SSID: tablets, BSSID: 00:00:00:00:00:00, MAC: 02:00:00:00:00:00, Supplicant state: SCANNING, RSSI: -127, Link speed: -1Mbps, Frequency: -1MHz, Net ID: -1, Metered hint: false, score: 0
02-22 18:13:16.982 3147-3147/? I/System.out: wifi ip adress: 0
02-22 18:13:16.982 3147-3147/? I/System.out: Unable to get host address.
02-22 18:13:16.987 3147-3147/? I/System.out: wifi configurations (all): 1
02-22 18:13:16.988 3147-3147/? I/System.out: found our network: ID: 0 SSID: "tablets" PROVIDER-NAME: null BSSID: null FQDN: null PRIO: 1
02-22 18:13:16.988 3147-3147/? I/System.out:  numAssociation 79
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out:  KeyMgmt: NONE Protocols: WPA RSN
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out:  AuthAlgorithms: OPEN SHARED
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out:  PairwiseCiphers: TKIP CCMP
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out:  GroupCiphers: TKIP CCMP
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out:  PSK: 
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: Enterprise config:
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: password NULL
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: engine 0
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: client_cert NULL
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: anonymous_identity NULL
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: identity NULL
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: domain_suffix_match NULL
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: phase2 NULL
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: altsubject_match NULL
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: subject_match NULL
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: ca_cert NULL
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: phase1 NULL
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: key_id NULL
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: engine_id NULL
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: eap NULL
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: IP config:
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: IP assignment: STATIC
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: Static configuration: IP address 192.168.0.16/24 Gateway 192.168.0.1  DNS servers: [ 8.8.8.8 ] Domains
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: Proxy settings: NONE
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out:  autoJoinBSSID=any cuid=1000 cname=android.uid.system:1000 luid=1000 lname=android.uid.system:1000 lcuid=10027 userApproved=USER_APPROVED noInternetAccessExpected=false roamingFailureBlackListTimeMilli: 1000
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: triggeredLow: 0 triggeredBad: 0 triggeredNotHigh: 0
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: ticksLow: 0 ticksBad: 0 ticksNotHigh: 0
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: triggeredJoin: 0
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: autoJoinBailedDueToLowRssi: false
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: autoJoinUseAggressiveJoinAttemptThreshold: 0
02-22 18:13:16.989 3147-3147/? I/System.out: SSID: "tablets"
02-22 18:13:16.990 3147-3147/? I/System.out: wifi configuration status is disabled: false
02-22 18:13:16.990 3147-3147/? I/System.out: disconnect() returns: true
02-22 18:13:16.990 3147-3147/? I/System.out: enabling our network: 0
02-22 18:13:16.992 589-652/? E/WifiConfigStore:  rewrite network history for "tablets"WEP
02-22 18:13:16.993 589-652/? E/WifiConfigStore: saveWifiConfigBSSID Setting BSSID for "tablets"WEP to any
02-22 18:13:17.005 3147-3147/? I/System.out: enableNetwork() returns: true
02-22 18:13:17.005 3147-3147/? I/System.out: trying to recommect to wifi.
02-22 18:13:17.005 3147-3147/? I/System.out: reconnect returns: true
02-22 18:13:17.006 3147-3147/? I/System.out: wifi ip adress: 0
02-22 18:13:17.006 3147-3147/? I/System.out: ip address: null
02-22 18:13:17.014 3147-3162/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-22 18:13:17.069 3147-3162/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
02-22 18:13:17.071 3147-3162/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-22 18:13:17.276 589-607/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed acme.wifi/.MainActivity: +447ms
02-22 18:13:17.290 1240-1240/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()
02-22 18:13:17.295 1581-1928/? I/Icing: Indexing B239306A9E3DAA7657A38D5F432BA0C9B208F125 from com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
02-22 18:13:17.351 1581-1928/? I/Icing: Indexing done B239306A9E3DAA7657A38D5F432BA0C9B208F125
02-22 18:13:21.271 1067-1067/? I/ConfigService: onDestroy
02-22 18:13:26.315 589-633/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
02-22 18:13:26.406 1396-3190/? I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi: Updating corpora: APPS=com.google.android.gms, CONTACTS=MAYBE
02-22 18:13:26.406 1581-3189/? D/PackageBroadcastService: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=com.google.android.gms
02-22 18:13:26.423 1581-3189/? I/PackageBroadcastService: Null package name or gms related package.  Ignoreing.
02-22 18:13:26.439 1396-3190/? I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi: UpdateCorporaTask done [took 33 ms] updated apps [took 33 ms] 
02-22 18:13:26.454 1476-1476/? V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi: DISABLE
02-22 18:13:26.454 1581-1928/? I/Icing: updateResources: need to parse f{com.google.android.gms}
02-22 18:13:26.461 1476-1476/? I/GCoreNlp: shouldConfirmNlp, NLP off. Ensuring opt-in disabled
02-22 18:13:26.501 589-601/? D/ActivityRecognitionProxy: AR HW instance not available, binding will be a no-op.
02-22 18:13:26.534 1344-1344/? I/Launcher: Deferring update until onResume
02-22 18:13:31.196 1712-1755/? D/Finsky: [120] AppStatesReplicator.handleContentSyncResponse: Completed 0 account content syncs with 0 successful.
02-22 18:13:31.197 1712-1712/? D/Finsky: [1] ContentSyncService$5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
02-22 18:14:10.384 589-626/? W/qcom_sensors_hal: hal_sensor1_data_cb: SENSOR1_MSG_TYPE_BROKEN_PIPE
02-22 18:14:10.400 3223-3223/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
02-22 18:14:10.400 3223-3223/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
02-22 18:14:10.401 3223-3223/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
02-22 18:14:10.428 3223-3225/? W/Sensors: sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=11, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=b6fcaa00
02-22 18:14:10.442 3223-3227/? W/Sensors: sns_sam_app.c(6827):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
02-22 18:14:10.463 3223-3229/? E/Sensors: sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
02-22 18:14:17.291 1240-1365/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator.LanguageModelFlusher: run()
02-22 18:14:17.291 1240-1365/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: flushDynamicLanguageModels()
02-22 18:14:17.332 1067-1067/? I/ConfigService: onCreate
02-22 18:14:22.401 1067-1067/? I/ConfigService: onDestroy
02-22 18:15:42.734 589-626/? W/qcom_sensors_hal: hal_sensor1_data_cb: SENSOR1_MSG_TYPE_BROKEN_PIPE
02-22 18:15:42.750 3238-3238/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
02-22 18:15:42.750 3238-3238/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
02-22 18:15:42.751 3238-3238/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
02-22 18:15:42.776 3238-3240/? W/Sensors: sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=11, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=b6f68a00
02-22 18:15:42.858 3238-3242/? W/Sensors: sns_sam_app.c(6827):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
02-22 18:15:42.880 3238-3246/? E/Sensors: sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
02-22 18:17:15.204 589-626/? W/qcom_sensors_hal: hal_sensor1_data_cb: SENSOR1_MSG_TYPE_BROKEN_PIPE
02-22 18:17:15.220 3252-3252/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
02-22 18:17:15.220 3252-3252/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
02-22 18:17:15.220 3252-3252/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
02-22 18:17:15.247 3252-3254/? W/Sensors: sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=11, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=b6ff2a00
02-22 18:17:15.339 3252-3258/? W/Sensors: sns_sam_app.c(6827):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
02-22 18:17:15.365 3252-3260/? E/Sensors: sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
02-22 18:18:47.764 589-626/? W/qcom_sensors_hal: hal_sensor1_data_cb: SENSOR1_MSG_TYPE_BROKEN_PIPE
02-22 18:18:47.832 3272-3272/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
02-22 18:18:47.833 3272-3272/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
02-22 18:18:47.835 3272-3272/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
02-22 18:18:47.865 3272-3276/? W/Sensors: sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=11, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=b6feca00
02-22 18:18:47.943 3272-3278/? W/Sensors: sns_sam_app.c(6827):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
02-22 18:18:47.963 3272-3280/? E/Sensors: sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
02-22 18:20:20.354 589-626/? W/qcom_sensors_hal: hal_sensor1_data_cb: SENSOR1_MSG_TYPE_BROKEN_PIPE
02-22 18:20:20.418 3294-3294/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
02-22 18:20:20.419 3294-3294/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
02-22 18:20:20.420 3294-3294/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
02-22 18:20:20.446 3294-3296/? W/Sensors: sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=11, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=b6fa3a00
02-22 18:20:20.524 3294-3298/? W/Sensors: sns_sam_app.c(6827):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
02-22 18:20:20.541 3294-3300/? E/Sensors: sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
02-22 18:21:52.814 589-626/? W/qcom_sensors_hal: hal_sensor1_data_cb: SENSOR1_MSG_TYPE_BROKEN_PIPE
02-22 18:21:52.837 3307-3307/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
02-22 18:21:52.837 3307-3307/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
02-22 18:21:52.838 3307-3307/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
02-22 18:21:52.867 3307-3309/? W/Sensors: sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=11, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=b6f79a00
02-22 18:21:52.959 3307-3313/? W/Sensors: sns_sam_app.c(6827):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
02-22 18:21:52.979 3307-3315/? E/Sensors: sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
02-22 18:21:59.123 589-601/? I/UsageStatsService: User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
```

is there any way to tell that the router is turned off?

thanks

Comment: could you do something for the formatting? I don't think anyone would go through that wall of log.

Comment: i put it in quotes, but that does not seem to help much.

Comment: i think i fixed the formatting.

Comment: what do you mean by `turned off`?

Comment: pulled out power cord to router

Comment: but what do you mean you want to know if it is turned off? how would you know that if the router simply is too far?