# 2013 nexus 7 android 6.0.1 how to wait for initialization to complete

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-6.0-marshmallow, nexus-7

my onCreate() looks like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new Thread(new IpAddressCallable()).start();
    int n=100;
    for(int i=1;i<=n&&!gotWifiUpOrFail;i++)
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("5 caught: "+e);
        }
    initialize();
}
```

i need to wait to [force a wifi conection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282807/android-studio-1-5-1-marshmallow-no-internet-access-detected-wont-automaticall) since the tablets come up in a: "no internet access detected won't automatically reconnect" mode (apparently since 5.1 or so).

the initialization buids the gui and does a: setContentView(relativeLayout), so i can not run this from another thread.

is this sane way to wait for something like this?

Comment: how about performing the next steps in onStart()??

Comment: i could do a little there, but i still need to wait for most of it. i could configure logging a little and setup the media player.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you normally use intents or receivers for this sort of thing? I thought hard-coded wait loops were frowned upon.  Maybe these will help:

[How to detect when WIFI Connection has been established in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established-in-android)

[Wifi Connect-Disconnect Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362314/wifi-connect-disconnect-listener)

[CONNECTIVITY_ACTION intent received twice when Wifi connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276032/connectivity-action-intent-received-twice-when-wifi-connected)

Comment: hi bill, i need to force a connection (see the link to my other question). my program needs to wait until the wifi is connected.  an intent might be useful, not sure what an intent is really.